# c++ compiler errors in include files

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to compile c++ program and getting errors that I have no clue what they mean. The error seems to comes from cpp_type_traits.h included in cmath

c++ -o exprtk_test exprtk_simple_example_19.cpp
In file included from /system/gnu_library/lib/gcc/i686-stratus-vos/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/cmath:50,
                 from /USERS/Dev/TumeloQ/cpp_includes/exprtk.hpp:39,
                 from exprtk_simple_example_19.cpp:24:
/system/gnu_library/lib/gcc/i686-stratus-vos/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:75: error: template with C linkage

Comment: can you explain it with more details? Like code which you are tying to compile. other code is working ?

Comment: The code I am trying to compile is C++ math expression parser exprtk. I am compiling an example program that comes with the code.

Comment: gcc 3.4.6 is ten years old...

Comment: Sometimes errors are detected in places that are remote from the actual code that causes them. That seems to be the case here. Look at the code that `#include`s cmath, in the vicinity of line 24 in exprtk_simple_example_19.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from your question but quite possibly you are declaring a template or a function within an `extern "C"` block or qualifier. That is not allowed and is treated as an error.